# PHP CodeSniffer Config installed_paths set to ../../elasticsearch,../../codeception,../../ Magento 2

Tags: magento2, installation, composer

I am going to install Magento using the composer.
I ran this command,

> composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/
>   magento/project-community-edition

There is showing me an error white installing the package. Please check below screenshot for further information.

[image]

**Note:** I have installed elastic search package on my server. But i don't think this error is related to the elasticsearch. Can you guys help me?

Thanks,

Comment: did you found any solution @sunny

Comment: Are you able to solve this ?

Answer (score 2):

Please install it using composer your error may be solved by installing this

If you use Composer, you can install PHP_CodeSniffer system-wide with the following command:

```
composer global require "squizlabs/php_codesniffer=*"
```

Make sure you have the composer bin dir in your PATH. The default value is ~/.composer/vendor/bin/, but you can check the value that you need to use by running

`composer global config bin-dir --absolute.`

Or alternatively, include a dependency for squizlabs/php_codesniffer in your composer.json file. For example:

```
{
    "require-dev": {
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "3.*"
    }
}
```

Comment: this is already mentioned in composer.json

Comment: [Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\RuntimeException]
  The "--absolute." option does not exist.

Comment: use --absolute command without fullstop at last.

Answer (score 0):

I have sometimes faced this issue and mostly they were related to php version.

Lets check the requirement of your magento version, your php version . Even php_codesniffer requirement ( if have )